# How to avoid poor rendering performance when drawing +100k geographic data

Tags: gis, bokeh

I'm currently using Bokeh, an interactive visualization library, to draw over 100k geographic data. I'm currently having some performance issues due to the high number of data.

There is any way to optimize geographic data when we are using such a huge input data? Any algorithm can be applied to optimize this?

[image: My bokeh output]

Comment: The image alone does not give enough detail. But even with an explanation of what it represents the question will still be very (too ?) broad. What do you mean by "performance issues" ? 100k is not that much. You should provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to allow people reproduce your image.

Comment: For exemple, when i try to zoom out/in, it's not smooth at all. It would be nice if i could implement an algorithm which could reduce the number of datapoints or even load progressively a map, just like google maps.

Comment: You can try adjusting Bokeh's  [level of detail](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/tools.html#controlling-level-of-detail) settings to get a smoother zoom.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [GeoViews](http://geoviews.org) + [Datashader](http://datashader.org), which will generate Bokeh objects that pre-render the data into a fixed-sized image before display.

Comment: The links do not work for me for some reason, however http://datashader.org/ and http://geo.holoviews.org/ do